# Translation for book title "The Other Side", differences between capitalization

Tags: english-to-japanese

I'm writing a book called The Other Side

I was curious what the Japanese translation for the title would be. I tried Google Translate and got two different answers:

The Other Side -
向こう側 /
Mukō-gawa

The other side -
反対側 /
Hantaisoku

Which is correct? Are either of them correct?

Thanks in advance. :) I have no prior experience with Japanese, I'm just curious.

Comment: It depends. The other side of what?

Comment: Hard to describe. Main character is in a depressing stage of his life, and he's looking for "the other side" of his life, a happier side.

Comment: @Wahh (1) Don't trust machine translation for Japanese-English, the quality is much worse than you expect. (2) Recent neural models sometimes go wacky like this when you hit their funny bones.

Comment: In actual practice of literary translation, translated title may or may not be faithful to the original one (in whatever language).

Comment: Ah I see Broccoli. Well that's fine, I don't mind if it's not a direct translation, the japanese version may be more charming anyway! If anyone wants to take a shot at translating it, feel free. :)

Comment: Also, 反対側 is read *hantaigawa*, not *hantaisoku*.

Answer (score 3):

Basically...

- 向こう側 refers to a distant place over a big thing (e.g., "the other side of this building", "the country over the sea", "somewhere over the rainbow", "the person over the phone")
- 反対側 and 逆側 refer to the opposite side of something (e.g, "the other side of a dining table", "the other side of a stick", "the other lane of a road") 反対/逆 means "opposite".
- 裏側 refers to the other side of a sheet-like structure, which is often hidden (e.g., "the other side of a coin", "inside a shirt", "behind the wall", "under the veil")

Now, "a (person's) life" is 人生, and "X of (my) life" is 人生のX. 人生の向こう側 sounds like somewhere you reach after you have finished your life, or some sort of spiritual world beyond the concept of life. 人生の裏側 sounds like the hidden, darker side of one's life. These are probably not what you want. 人生の反対側 or 人生の逆側 usually makes little sense and is hard to describe, but if you indeed want to refer to something poetic like "the other (happier) side of my life", this may be a valid option. We do say 正反対の人生 or 真逆の人生 referring to a completely different and contrasting life path (e.g., gang vs police, happy vs miserable, athlete vs scientist).

A human translator might interpret the concept of your book and choose other titles like あちら側 (literally "that side"), もう一つの人生 ("another life"), ありえた人生 ("life that had been possible") and so on.

Anyway, you should not rely on machine translations because they usually do not understand nuances and contexts. In this case, even a human cannot say which is correct unless you provide enough context.